# How to save output of a PHP CLI process to a file

Tags: php, command-line-interface, background-process

I've got a PHP script that generates some HTML reports, which take a long time to generate (over 20-30 seconds).

Right now , the file reports.php  is echoing the output to the user via the browser, saving the reports using output buffers.  (EDIT: The name of the report file is a code generated by reports.php) :

```
<?php
   ob_start(); 

   [...echo all the html for the tables in the report...]

   file_put_contents('report.html', ob_get_contents());

   // end buffering and displaying page
   ob_end_flush(); 
 ?>
```

Since my process often takes a long time,I don't want the user to be stuck looking at the screen for a long time waiting for the output, or even worse, timing out.

I did a bit of searching and found out that the best way to avoid this would be to launch this process in the background using PHP CLI. I'm using a separate file:

```
<?php
echo 'Your report is being generated. You'll get it via email.';
exec('nohup php reports.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
?>
```

But this solution does not let me save using the output buffer. I guess it's because I'm redirecting to /dev/null?

I then tried just launching the process to the background

```
<?php
echo 'Your report is being generated. You'll get it via email.';
exec('nohup php reports.php');
?>
```

But this still won't save. What am I doing wrong?
Are there any options to save this report to disk without making the user wait with the browser window open for the report to be echoed back?

Comment: `exec('nohup php reports.php > output.txt');`?

Comment: Redirecting stdout shouldn't have an effect on file_put_contents of the output buffer.

Comment: @Daniil the problem is, the name of output.txt is a code generated by reports.php

Comment: @frz3993 it seems the problem is the nohup. When I execute the launcher script via the command line, without nohup, it works

Comment: After some searching it seems the problem lies with SuPHP and exec(). It seems SuPHP does not allow background tasks to be run.